# Can't Get NameSpace from Parsing XML File Using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, parsing, rss, nokogiri

I'm looking to parse a RSS feed such as http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:70685608/sounds.rss using Nokogiri.  However despite how many different ways I try to parse the document, I'm unable to get the data elements I want.

For example, if I want to get the itunes:name block, I've tried the following below and none of these is returning what I want.

```
page = HTTParty.get('http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:70685608/sounds.rss')
parse_feed = Nokogiri::HTML(page)

#tried 1
parse_feed.css('channel|itunes:owner')
#tried 2
parse_feed.css('itunes:name')
#tried 3
parse_feed.xpath('//itunes:email')
```

Am I just way off here on my xpath or css searches to get the block I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me by switching `Nokogiri::HTML(page)` with `Nokogiri::XML(page)`.  Then, I could use xpath to extract the itunes:name block:

```
page = HTTParty.get('http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:70685608/sounds.rss')
parse_feed = Nokogiri::XML(page)
itunes_name = parse_feed.xpath("//itunes:name")
# do stuff
```